# How correctly make project structure in IntelliJ IDEA for Spring Boot microservices?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, microservices

I used to work with Monolithic architecture and I don't have experience with Microservices. I need to create project with some modules (microservices).

1. auth
2. messages

I use IntelliJ IDEA for my project.

Can you explain me what is the best practice for microservices project structure in this IDE?

Should I use Maven or it is better to add IntelliJ IDEA project modules?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/03/develop-spring-boot-applications-more-productively-with-intellij-idea-14-1/)?

Comment: You can choose any structure that fits you, any suggestion here will be based on someone else their opinion and opinionated questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow. (Besides that this question is fairly broad.)

Answer (score -2):

There are no right or wrong answer but in a monolith, you will probably end up with a structure like this (Domain Driven - Profile Domain, BankAccountDomain):

- main

  - profile

    - model

      - Profile.java
      - ProfileRequest.java
      - ProfileResponse.java
    - ProfileController.java
    - ProfileService.java
    - ProfileRepository.java
  - bankaccount

    - model

      - BankAccount.java
      - BankAccountRequest.java
      - BankAccountResponse.java
    - BankAccountController.java
    - BankAccountService.java
    - BankAccountRepository.java
- test

What you can do if you go to the extreme of microservice have each domain as a seperate microservice

You can use grade or maven to have different projects (microservice) within the same repo if thats what you are looking for.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html